# Finding dates in string and changing their format

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
"startDate = '2018-03-21'; endDate = '2022-06-28'; lasttime = '2022-06-10T16:42' and name='Alex'"
```

Is there a way to find dates in this string and change their format to (dd/MM/YYYY) and (dd/MM/YYYY hh:MM:ss)? So the result will be:

```
"startDate = '21/03/2018'; endDate = '28/06/2022'; lasttime = '10/06/2022 16:42:00' and name='Alex'"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with regex, I made one, which you can let yourself explain [here](https://regexr.com/6olt2). It uses `String.prototype.replaceAll` with a [function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) and regex [groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#using_groups)

```js
const string = "startDate = '2018-03-21'; endDate = '2022-06-28'; lasttime = '2022-06-10T16:42' and name='Alex'";

const regex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})(T(\d{2}):(\d{2}))?/g;

const newString = string.replaceAll(regex, (match, year, month, day, time, hour, minute) => {
  return `${day}/${month}/${year}${time ? ` ${hour}:${minute}:00` : ""}`;
});

console.log(newString);
```

Another version is here using [named groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#using_named_groups), it is maybe easier to maintain, but named groups are not supported in IE

```js
const string = "startDate = '2018-03-21'; endDate = '2022-06-28'; lasttime = '2022-06-10T16:42' and name='Alex'";

const regex = /(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})(?<time>T(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minute>\d{2}))?/g;

const newString = string.replaceAll(regex, (...args) => {
  // the named groups are stored under the last index of args
  const {
    year,
    month,
    day,
    time,
    hour,
    minute
  } = args[args.length - 1];

  return `${day}/${month}/${year}${time ? ` ${hour}:${minute}:00` : ""}`;
});

console.log(newString);
```